# What are the supported formats for embedding audio in HTML5?

Tags: html

I recently read that HTML 5 comes with a standard way of embedding audio files.
I need to use this feature but I don't know which are the supported files.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="track.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Only mpeg ?

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend, check this out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp & http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the  tag.
The  tag defines sound, such as music or other audio streams.

Currently, there are 3 supported file formats for the  element: MP3, Wav, and Ogg:

```
Browser MP3 Wav Ogg
IE      YES NO  NO
Chrome  YES YES YES
Firefox NO  YES YES
Safari  YES YES NO
Opera   NO  YES YES
```

**Update**: Firefox 21 running on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, and Android now supports MP3.

MIME Types for Audio FormatsFormat  MIME-type

```
MP3 audio/mpeg
Ogg audio/ogg
Wav audio/wav
```

Answer (score 3):

[The supported formats are MP3, WAV and Ogg.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) You'll need to include at least two of these if you want to support all the major browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
Internet Exploree: MP3
Chrome: MP3, WAV, OGG
Firefox: WAV, OGG
Safari: MP3, WAV
Opera: WAV, OGG
```

**[Find More](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)**

Comment: Each new release of a browser may support more file formats. The version of the browser is very important when it comes to any new html5 features